# How to display an indicator of the process of turning a large pixmap?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Need to rotate the big pixmap(from gallery) in my game.
I use the following code for this.

For example:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

private int w = 720, h = 1280;
private Stage stage;
private Image bigImg, button, rotationIndicator;

private Pixmap pixmap0;
private Pixmap pixmap90;
private Texture textureBigImg;
private String buttonPath = "badlogic.jpg", bigImgPath = "DSC_0006.JPG"; //DSC_0006.JPG: 5504x3096

private Thread thread;

@Override
public void create () {
    stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(w, h));

    button = new Image(new Texture(buttonPath));
    textureBigImg = new Texture(bigImgPath);
    bigImg = new Image(textureBigImg);
    rotationIndicator = new Image(new Texture(buttonPath));

    rotationIndicator.setPosition(720-256,0);
    button.setPosition(0,0);
    bigImg.setBounds( 0,256, w, w*3096/5504f);

    pixmap0 = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal(bigImgPath));

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rotation();
        }
    });

    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
            stage.addActor(rotationIndicator);

            rotation();                                 //rotationIndicator draw only after the turn process.
            //thread.start();                           //I get a black screen.

        }
    });

    stage.addActor(button);
    stage.addActor(bigImg);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

private void rotation() {
    pixmap90 = new Pixmap(pixmap0.getHeight(), pixmap0.getWidth(), pixmap0.getFormat());

    for (int y = 0, a = 0; y<pixmap0.getWidth(); ++y, ++a) {
        for (int x = 0, b = pixmap0.getHeight(); x<pixmap0.getHeight(); ++x, --b) {
            pixmap90.drawPixel(x, y, pixmap0.getPixel(a, b));
        }
    }

    textureBigImg.dispose();
    textureBigImg = new Texture(pixmap90);
    textureBigImg.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    bigImg.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(textureBigImg)));
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    pixmap0.dispose();
    pixmap90.dispose();
    textureBigImg.dispose();
}
```

}

The problem is that the big picture turns too long. From this freezing program.

I tried to do it in a separate thread, but I get a black screen.

I tried to display the turn indicator, but it is drawn only after the turn process.

Now I am trying to reduce pixmap, but on weak devices there is still freezing.

Comment: You should be able to handle this on a separate thread. Show your code for doing this on another thread.

Comment: I added the code for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create new Texture objects or manipulate them in separate threads because they are OpenGL objects. Your `rotate()` method should send a runnable back to the GL thread to load the Texture after you're done creating the rotated pixmap.

So take all the code after your for loop in `rotate()` and wrap it in a Runnable. Call `Gdx.app.postRunnable()`.

Comment: Thanks It works. I tried to use Gdx.app.post Runnable (), but apparently not where needed.